# Merge sort auxiliary array creation/ middle question

Tags: java

I have some questions about my code. I've marked it with `---><---` down below.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10};
        int[] aux = new int[arr.length];
        sort(arr, aux, 0, arr.length - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] arr, int[] aux, int low, int high) {

        // what does these lines do? --->
        if (low >= high) { 
            return;
        }
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; // why cant it just be high - low / 2
        //<--- These lines

        sort(arr, aux, low, mid); //sorts left side
        sort(arr, aux, mid + 1, high); //sorts right side
        merge(arr, aux, low, mid, high); //merges the two sides
    }

    public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] aux, int low, int mid, int high) {
        for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
            aux[k] = arr[k];
        }
        //copies the array into an aux array

        int i = low; //counter for the left side
        int j = mid + 1; //counter for the right side

        for (int k = low; k <= high; k++) {
            if (i > mid) { //if i > mid meaning that if the left side of the array is empty then use the right side
                arr[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else if (j > high) { //if j > high then right side of array has been used so use left
                arr[k] = aux[i++];
            }
            else if (aux[i] <= aux[j]) { //if value of left side is <= value of right then bring leftside value up to original array
                arr[k] = aux[i++];
            }
            else { //value of right side is <= value of left so bring rightside value up to original array
                arr[k] = aux[j++];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a part of the merge from GeeksForGeeks

```java
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) { 
    /* Create temp arrays */
    // These lines --->
    int L[] = new int [n1]; 
    int R[] = new int [n2]; 
    //<---
}
```

With G4Geek's temp arrays:

- Is it getting created every single time merge is called?
- Does the memory just stay there?
- Is the current code that I have better practice?

Thanks.

Comment: no idea why its not bolding.

Comment: You cannot use bold inside code, use markers such as arrows instead.